# Spark streaming: ERROR StreamingContext: failed to construct kafka consumer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to access a kafka topic by using spark streaming. I don´t think that i missed any dependencies or imports, but when I try to run my code, which is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String URL = "spark://localhost:7077";

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Kafka-test").setMaster(URL);
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(1));

    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:6667");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "ID1");
    kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", false);

    Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList("MAX_LEGO", "CanBeDeleted");

    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
            ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));

    JavaPairDStream<Object, Object> max = stream.mapToPair(record -> new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value()));
    max.count();
    max.print();

    ssc.start();

}
```

I receive an error message:

`18/02/10 16:57:08 ERROR streaming.StreamingContext: Error starting the context, marking it as stopped
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:703)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:553)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:536)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.Subscribe.onStart(ConsumerStrategy.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.consumer(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.start(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach_quick(ParArray.scala:143)
    at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach(ParArray.scala:136)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:972)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:969)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
    at ... run in separate thread using org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils ... ()
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:578)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:556)
    at org.kafkaConnection2.main(kafkaConnection2.java:50)`

`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer is not an instance of org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:624)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:553)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:536)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.Subscribe.onStart(ConsumerStrategy.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.consumer(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream.start(DirectKafkaInputDStream.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$start$5.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach_quick(ParArray.scala:143)
    at scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray$ParArrayIterator.foreach(ParArray.scala:136)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.leaf(ParIterableLike.scala:972)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply$mcV$sp(Tasks.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$$anonfun$tryLeaf$1.apply(Tasks.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.parallel.Task$class.tryLeaf(Tasks.scala:51)
    at scala.collection.parallel.ParIterableLike$Foreach.tryLeaf(ParIterableLike.scala:969)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks$WrappedTask$class.compute(Tasks.scala:152)
    at scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingForkJoinTasks$WrappedTask.compute(Tasks.scala:443)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)`

My assumption is that maybe the bootstrapserver is set wrong or something else went wrong by connecting to kafka...

Please don´nt be annoyed by this propably rather stupid question but I just started using Spark and kafka

Comment: Can you post the full error message including the 'Caused By'?

Comment: Kafka typically runs on 9092 not 6667

Comment: Added the full error message

Comment: I tried to change the ports but it didn´t change a thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer instead of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer as you are getting the below exception

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer is not an instance of org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:205)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:624)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:553)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.(KafkaConsumer.java:536)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.Subscribe.onStart(ConsumerStrategy.scala:83)
    at

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I shouldn´t have used auto import in eclipse...my fault